# Issue while fetching text[] from json

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a requirement of parsing text array from json value in postgres stored procedure.  as below,

Below is my procedure implementation,

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  updateEventTable(inputdata json)
    RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE
        msgList text[];  
    BEGIN

    msgList := inputdata ->'messageList';

        INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("MESSAGE_LIST") 
                            values (msgList );      
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Below is my stored procedure invocation with the JSON string in the parameter field,

```
    SELECT * from updateEventTable('{
        "messageList": ["Message1", "Message2"]
    }');
```

Am i following the right approach in fetching the text array from json.. please guide me here. 
   "MESSAGE_LIST" field in the table MyTable is of type text array. Is there any json support function in postgres which can do this job?

My requirement is the fetch messageList's value from json  as text array and store in the database

Comment: I dont think json can have `text[]`, as it is postgres data type, not specified in json...

Comment: Thanks @VaoTsun for the swift response. May i please know what could be the work around for this. Currently i am manually filling the text array as below,

Comment: please populate json sample

Comment: DECLARE 
    msgTextJson json;  
    msgTextArray text[];
    
 msgTextJson := inputdata->'messageList';
 msgTextArray[0] = msgTextJson->0;
 msgTextArray[1] = msgTextJson->1;

Comment: json sample,   {
                  "messageList": ["Message1", "Message2"]
                  }

Comment: then @klin already answered :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inputdata ->'messageList'` is a json array. You should unpack it with `json_array_elements_text()` and aggregate its elements to a text array:

```
...
    SELECT array_agg(elem)
    INTO msgList
    FROM json_array_elements_text(inputdata ->'messageList') elem;

    INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("MESSAGE_LIST") 
                        values (msgList );      
...
```

Comment: Awesome guys . Thanks a lot for your help. It worked.